# Spark DataFrame losing string data in yarn-client mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

By some reason if I'm adding new column, appending string to existing data/column or creating new DataFrame from code, it misinterpreting string data, so show() doesn't work properly, filters (such as withColumn, where, when, etc.) doesn't work ether.

Here is example code:

```
object MissingValue {
  def hex(str: String): String = str.getBytes("UTF-8").map(f => Integer.toHexString((f&0xFF)).toUpperCase).mkString("-")

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MissingValue")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val list = List((101,"ABC"),(102,"BCD"),(103,"CDE"))
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(list).map(f => Row(f._1,f._2))
    val schema = StructType(StructField("COL1",IntegerType,true)::StructField("COL2",StringType,true)::Nil)
    val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
    df.show()

    val str = df.first().getString(1)
    println(s"${str} == ${hex(str)}")

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

If I run it in local mode then everything works as expected:

```
+----+----+
|COL1|COL2|
+----+----+
| 101| ABC|
| 102| BCD|
| 103| CDE|
+----+----+

ABC == 41-42-43
```

But when I run the same code in yarn-client mode it produces:

```
+----+----+
|COL1|COL2|
+----+----+
| 101| ^E^@^@|
| 102| ^E^@^@|
| 103| ^E^@^@|
+----+----+

^E^@^@ == 5-0-0
```

This problem exists only for string values, so first column (Integer) is fine.

Also if I'm creating rdd from the dataframe then everything is fine `i.e.  df.rdd.take(1).apply(0).getString(1)`

I'm using Spark 1.5.0 from CDH 5.5.2

**EDIT:**
It seems that this happens when the difference between driver memory and executor memory is too high `--driver-memory xxG --executor-memory yyG` i.e. when I decreasing executor memory or increasing driver memory then the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug related to executor memory and Oops size:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9725  
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10914  
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17706

It is fixed in Spark version 1.5.2